# How to sort 5 numbers without using list, tuples or even dictionaries? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

is there any way to sort 5 numbers in ascending or descending order without using list, tuples and dictionaries? The 5 numbers are given by the user.

i'm new at programming, if someone could give me some help it would be great.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you storing these 5 numbers? In variables?

Comment: Why? Those are the normal things to sort things in. You could use 5 variables, say `foo1` to `foo5` and implement your own sorting algorithm. You could write a function that yields the 5 values in turn and then pass that to `sorted` (but you'd end up with a list).

Comment: Yup I tried storing those 5 numbers in variables

Comment: My teacher asked for it the last week, and he never give us the answer so I was wondering if it is possible to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to take some sorting algorithm and [unroll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling) it completely, using only your 5 variables. This approach is obviously not very practical.

```
a = int(input('a:'))
b = int(input('b:'))
c = int(input('c:'))
d = int(input('d:'))
e = int(input('e:'))

if a > b: tmp = a; a = b; b = tmp
if b > c: tmp = b; b = c; c = tmp
if c > d: tmp = c; c = d; d = tmp
if d > e: tmp = d; d = e; e = tmp

if a > b: tmp = a; a = b; b = tmp
if b > c: tmp = b; b = c; c = tmp
if c > d: tmp = c; c = d; d = tmp

if a > b: tmp = a; a = b; b = tmp
if b > c: tmp = b; b = c; c = tmp

if a > b: tmp = a; a = b; b = tmp

print(f'{a} {b} {c} {d} {e}')
```

Comment: It's not very practical as you say, but it seems to work! 
Thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

Easy, with `sorted()`:

```
n = input()
print(sorted(n))
```

Output:

```
34215
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Or, without the list:

```
n = input()
print(''.join(sorted(n)))
```

Output:

```
53421
12345
```

Comment: Thank you for answer.

I forgot that the  numbers are whole numbers, but it solve what I asked xD

Comment: Glad to hear that :)